# Can you specify dependency checksums in Apache Ivy?

Tags: ant, ivy, checksum

I'm curious if there's a way to specify a checksum value for dependencies in an ivy.xml file.

For example, I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="3.5.6-Final"
    force="true"/>
```

Would it be possible for me to do something like this?

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="3.5.6-Final"
    checksum="10249177261810a3ba8f3b9a468d06e0" force="true"/>
```

The primary reason I want to do this is for security, to ensure that the dependency on the remote repository has not been changed when I pull it down in the future. I would like to check it against the checksum value in my own ivy.xml file instead of that on the remote host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). These are local Maven repositories that can download jars from the various third party repositories.

Both can be set to cache remote artifacts locally and not to redownload them once downloaded. This will solve your problem of a jar in a remote repository being changed.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of checksums in ivy (and Maven for that matter) is to ensure that the download worked correctly and the file was not corrupted in transit or storage.

- ["checksum" attribute on resolvers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html)
- [Description of checksums in ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#checksum)

The only ivy functionality that use checksums for security checking is the [packager resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html). This makes sense since the packager repository files are designed to be hosted separately to the source files.

So in conclusion, the best solution is to following David's advice and deploy a Maven repository manager within your network. [Sonatype have recently offered SSL connectivity](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2013/01/secure-central-connectivity-artifactory-archiva-now-supported/) to Maven Central, which additionally protects you against remote repository spoofing.